# What's wrong with my code for using the camera?

Tags: android, camera

I'm very new to Android. I'm trying to use the camera with an image overlay. I've seen many threads discussing this topic, but they're still a little over my head. Here's my Activity:

```
package com.commonsware.android.skeleton;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

public class SimpleBulbActivity extends Activity {
    private Preview mPreview;
    FrameLayout preview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        //Setup the FrameLayout with the Camera Preview Screen
        mPreview = new Preview(this);
        preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.preview); 
        preview.addView(mPreview);
    }

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            // TODO: add more exception handling logic here
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }


    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

        List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size optimalSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, w, h);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(optimalSize.width, optimalSize.height);

        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

}
```

As you can see, I use the Preview class from the CameraPreview example that can be found in the docs. Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Camera Demo"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/buttonClick"
        android:text="Click" android:layout_gravity="center"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

So what I'm doing is creating the surface and then trying to add it to the layout inside of the preview FrameLayout. It's not working though. It crashes right away. Help would be awesome!

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.commonsware.android.skeleton"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".SimpleBulbActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
</manifest>
```

Apologies, here is the entire logcat. I see two exceptions in there, so maybe that's what's causing it?

```
12-20 16:16:10.843: ERROR/BatteryService(68): usbOnlinePath not found
12-20 16:16:10.843: ERROR/BatteryService(68): batteryVoltagePath not found
12-20 16:16:10.843: ERROR/BatteryService(68): batteryTemperaturePath not found
12-20 16:16:10.883: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(68): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
12-20 16:16:11.003: ERROR/SensorService(68): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)
12-20 16:16:15.923: ERROR/System(68): Failure starting core service
12-20 16:16:15.923: ERROR/System(68): java.lang.SecurityException
12-20 16:16:15.923: ERROR/System(68):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
12-20 16:16:15.923: ERROR/System(68):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
12-20 16:16:15.923: ERROR/System(68):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
12-20 16:16:15.923: ERROR/System(68):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)
12-20 16:16:15.953: ERROR/EventHub(68): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
12-20 16:16:15.953: ERROR/EventHub(68): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
12-20 16:16:16.564: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
12-20 16:16:16.564: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
12-20 16:16:16.564: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
12-20 16:16:16.564: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
12-20 16:16:16.564: ERROR/SoundPool(68): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
12-20 16:16:16.623: ERROR/UsbObserver(68): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 16:16:16.623: ERROR/UsbObserver(68):     at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)
12-20 16:16:16.623: ERROR/UsbObserver(68):     at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)
12-20 16:16:16.623: ERROR/UsbObserver(68):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)
12-20 16:16:17.233: ERROR/ThrottleService(68): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
12-20 16:16:20.224: ERROR/logwrapper(160): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-20 16:16:20.324: ERROR/logwrapper(162): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-20 16:16:20.394: ERROR/logwrapper(163): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1643)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326): Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3835)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
12-20 16:16:58.542: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(326):     ... 12 more
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1643)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355): Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3835)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
12-20 16:17:19.592: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(355):     ... 12 more
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1643)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3835)
12-20 16:18:11.932: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
```

Comment: please provide stacktrace from logcat

Comment: Without seeing your Manifest or the logcat, I can only make a guess. But one thing that I could expect to cause an almost immediate crash is a SecurityException. You must have the permission "android.permission.CAMERA" in your manifest: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CAMERA

Comment: I'm not sure what to look for in the logcat, but here are two lines that seemed related.

`12-20 15:24:15.282: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
12-20 15:24:16.619: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{406bf3e0 com.commonsware.android.skeleton/.SimpleBulbActivity}
`

Comment: I have the permission in my manifest.

Comment: http://androidforums.com/developer-101/432314-tutorial-use-logcat-post-problems.html

Comment: Unfortunately, the logcat output you have posted does not contain anything about your application. It contains logs from some other applications. I suggest you to clear logcat before starting your app, start your app and wait for crush, then post everything from logcat.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I did as suggested, I get the crash, but nothing is showing up in the log.

Comment: It won't let me submit an answer to my own question. I was able to look at the logcat and see that an exception was being thrown when it tried to resume. Looked at `onResume();` and noticed I didn't have `super.onResume();` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `super.onResume()` in your `onResume()` implementation:

```
Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.commonsware.android.skeleton/com.commonsware.android.skeleton.SimpleBulbActivity} did not call through to super.onResume()
```